# How to install a SDK to VSTS build server ( unattended )

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

I have tried to install the latest Azure service fabric SDK. I have written this powershell script but not sure how to install it.

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope

 CurrentUser $down = New-Object System.Net.WebClient $url  =
 'http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK';

 $file = 'MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK.exe';
 $down.DownloadFile($url,$file);
 #$exec = New-Object -com shell.application
 #$exec.shellexecute($file);


 $command = “cmd.exe /c c:\MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK.exe /s /v`”/qn”

 $process = [WMICLASS]”\\localhost\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process”
 $process.Create($command)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can’t install SDK on VSTS hosted agent. You can setup a private build agent with necessary SDK installed, then queue build by using this build agent.

You can refer to this article to setup a windows agent: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Comment: thanks for the response. I have setup the build server. If you want to update your apps in a cycle you can not use hosted build servers.